# Pop up on swipe?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to pop up new window on swipe event, like on click?

Browser's bockers for some browsers blocking it. So far I tried to trigger click event on swipe, tried to delay pop up, tried to use e.preventDefault(), tried to window.document.write(htmlcontent), so far nothing really helped.

The swipe falls into iframe and returns the event, by which pop up is called. So unfortunately for me it is direct interaction of user, but it doesn't register as one. So generally is there any way to avoid pop up blocker if the interaction is not direct?

The message returned with postmessage, the message is true or false. If true at the touchend pop up window suppose to appear with sign in fields.

Comment: Forgot to mention, for mobile

Comment: Well, swipe works only for mobile, so kind of mentioned it 

Comment: It's quite simple. On the swipe of the element, opening popup window. The element is iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't edit the original questions, though here is a code snipped for you:
no pop-up blocking apeared, though even if you aprove pop-up the browser ignores.

```js
document.addEventListener('touchmove',e => {
  window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914104/pop-up-on-swipe")
})
```

**Note:** Touch Devices only

Comment: Sorry should've mentioned it. In opera, Firefox, Internet explorer. And it should be swipe event. Just a sec I'll throw the code. I didn't do it because it's standard, just didn't think there could be many other events.

Comment: I'm on the phone, so the code can take some time

Comment: You have right code, sorry. On the touched though.

Comment: copy code from my post

Comment: I think your browser's pop up blocker is switched off. It's blocking for me.